# Running a thread for a certain amount of time

Tags: c#

I have a method that reads my RFID reader with a thread,I want to keep this running for a certain amount of time,then stop it,whats the best way to do this?

For example:

**Run:**

```
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Perform(null, null, antennainfo);
```

Run for 5 seconds:

**Stop:**

```
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
```

Tried stopwatch but it's not threadsafe I think.

tried this:

```
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan RequiredTimeLine = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0);
        TimeSpan timeGone = new TimeSpan();

        ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Perform(null, null, antennainfo);
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (timeGone.Seconds < RequiredTimeLine.Seconds)
        {
            timeGone = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: How long `Perform` method will take to complete? Do you have the code for that method? Can you modify it?

Comment: Stopwatch *is* threadsafe - it just reads the processor performance counters using the Windows API.

Comment: Perform is actually from Motorola EMDK's,so i don't really know whats running under it,it keeps reading as long as you send it the stop code.

Comment: @Sin5k4 how you will now if successful read is accomplished? You need to stop it and then check what?

Comment: After stopping it;it returns an array of read tags,if none is read,its unsuccessful.

Comment: How were you using Stopwatch, and in what way did it not work? (Were you waiting in a busy loop? Always a no-no.)

Comment: And do you need to stop it to read that array of read tags?

Comment: Call perform in a separate thread, setup a timer for 5 seconds, call `Stop` in that timer?

Comment: Is `Perform` method a blocking call? I mean synchronous?

Comment: Nope perform is async.And yes,it needs to be stopped to get the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about,

```
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Perform(null, null, antennainfo);
await Task.Delay(5000);
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
```

or if your method is not `async`.

```
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Perform(null, null, antennainfo);
Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
```

---

I would caveat this answer, if it is important that 5 second period has a very accurate duration? `Task.Delay()` and `Thread.Sleep()` are not appropriate, on their own, for high accuracy timing.

---

Incidentally, `Stopwatch` has a `StartNew` factory method so you can do,

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Thing to time.
stopwatch.Stop();
```

Comment: Isn't `Task.Delay(5000).Wait()` just the same as `Thread.Sleep(5000)`?

Comment: The one drawback I see is that reading will take the same amount of time - even when it succeed earlier. If using CancellationToken you can abort thread both on timeout event and successfull reading event

Comment: @IvanSamygin good point but its not clear from the question that `Perform` will ever complete.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'd have to research but yes, I think that's right.

Comment: @Jodrell as I can see from question, Perform should return immediately (it's no sence to loop after calling it otherwise). But there's no info about complete notification.

Comment: @IvanSamygin therefore, what could you cancel based upon. Now, if `Perform` returned a `Task`...

Comment: Perform keeps running until you tell it to stop,so we don't know that.

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you to solve the problem

```
var timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(StopInventory), null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Perform(null, null, antennainfo);
```

here is the stop method

```
private void StopInventory(object obj)
{
    ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
    timer.Change( Timeout.Infinite , Timeout.Infinite ) ;
}
```

Comment: For this,I couldn't manage to stop it after 5000;it goes to StopInventory instantly,why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sleep:

```
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Perform(null, null, antennainfo);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
```

Or compare the elapsed time:

```
long ticks = DateTime.Ticks;
while(DateTime.Ticks - ticks < 50000000) // 5 seconds
{
    ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Perform(null, null, antennainfo);
}
ReaderAPI.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
```